# How to remove an element from array and update state without that element on the FlatList?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to remove the data from a FlatList that it renders the sales from a JSON file `data.json`
The problem is that when I remove the sale with a certain id and I go back to home page, it shows all the items again. So how can I remove the items from the source and the items will be removed for the whole life of the application until the user closes and reopens again?
Any help would be very much appreciated.

```
import data from './data.json';
```

```
{
    "sales": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "amount": 100
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "amount": 200
        },
   ]
}
```

```
state = {
    data: data.sales
  }
```

```
  onPressRemove(id) {
    this.setState(
    prevState => {
      let data = prevState.data.slice();
      let newId = 0;
      for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++){
        if (data[i].id === id){
          newId = i;
        }
      }
      data.splice(newId, 1)
      return { data };
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem right here is that where you go to another part of your app this component will **UNMOUNT** and when you go back to this component he will mount and use the state from the import (data.json). 
For this kind of problem, many people choose to go with **redux**.

Another way would be to keep the state on the parent and give it as a prop to this component, so even when that will unmount and mount again it **will still have the prop unchanged** (because parent never unmounts).

*If you have more questions in implementation, feel free to comment/share your code if you stuck implementing my answer.*

Comment: Thank you for that! :) I understand my problem, I was just thinking for any way around it.

Answer (score 1):

After operation update your state again

```
onPressRemove(id) {
    const { data } = this.state;
    let filteredData = data.filter(d=> d.id!==id);
    this.setState({data:filteredData});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

beside from using redux, alternatively you can update your data.json programatically using [fs](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs) , but since it become more difficult i recommend to try **redux**

Comment: I am new to React Native but Redux seems the way to go. :)